# Flutter iOS - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - ARCHIVE APP FROM XCODE

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, podfile

When I want to press Archive button from the Xcode, it gives UNRELAVANT this error:

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

How can I solve this problem? I tried:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub cache repair
delete podfile.lock
pod install
pod update
pod repo update
pod reintegrate
```

and so on. Also I checked that the app can run successfully for both emulator and REAL device. I can not archive it, I need your help dear community.

Thanks

Full Error:

```
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/kafile-app/ios/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/device_info_plus.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/aaefcfd1-5c95-11ed-8734-2e32217d8374/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: above error says phoneos/device_info_plus.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2) but I have no such package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with XCode 14.3 and you will need to update cocoapods to fix it:

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

In case this doesn't work, go to `/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh` and replace

`source="$(readlink "${source}")"`

with

`source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

Edit and reminder: You need to do this renaming procedure before every archive execution in case updating cocoapods doesn't work

Comment: second one has worked, and you have got A LOT OF THANKS from my side because of the UNRELAVANT problem. Thank you!